# HTTP GET 200 vs 204

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-200, http-status-code-204

We are designing a public API, and trying to figure out what is the best practice for GET with following cases:

**Path param:**

```
/orders/{orderId}
```

Found: 200 with a response body.
Not Found: 404.

**Query param:**

```
/Products/{productId}/orders?color={color}
```

Found orders: 200 with response body.

*Not found: Should this be a 200 or 204 or even a 404 in this case?*

In my opinion, it should be 200 or 204 as the resource is found in this case and the query parameter is only performing the filter effect. But should we return a 200 or 204 in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper REST response for empty table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366730/proper-rest-response-for-empty-table)

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924573/3012385

Comment: Ideally your REST response status code should be based on the net result of the request.
If the request gives a desired response than status code should be 2xx
and if the response is other way round then it should always give error response (4xx) .

So in your case it should be 404.

Comment: In you case; 404. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

(1) The first URL is for exactly one order.

(2) The second URL is for a list of 0 or more orders.

---

**Missing an order in the first response should be a 404,** since a not-an-order is not an order.

**Missing orders in the second response should be a 200,** since an empty list is still a list.