# Should a REST API return a 404 when POSTing a non-existing ID?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404

As far as I understand it, in addition to returning a `404 Not Found` for unknown *endpoints*, a REST API should also return a 404 in the following cases:

- requesting a resource with an ID that does not exist **in the path**: route `/users/{id}` exists, but `/users/123456` does not exist
- requesting a resource with an ID that does not exist **in the query parameters**: route `/search` exists, but `/search?user=123456` returns a 404 if the user does not exist (I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20922543/759866) a few years ago)

Now what about the use case where an endpoint accepts a JSON object with a number of fields, one of them being the ID of a user that does not exist:

```
POST /makeReservation HTTP/1.1
...

{
    "userId": 123456,
    ...
}
```

**Should this return a 404 as well**, or is this considered a different kind of error (validation error?) in this case?

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand it

I'd say your current understanding is a little bit more complicated than it should be.

[404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) means:

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

In case "target resource" is unclear, we can review the specification of the [Request Line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1).

> request-line   = method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF

> The request-target identifies the target resource upon which to apply the request, as defined in [Section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3).

In other words, `404` says "there is a problem with the spelling of the request-target".

Therefore, it is misleading to suggest that there is a problem with the request-target, when the actual problem is in the request body.

The error code you probably want for this case is [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

IANA's [HTTP Status Code Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) is a good place to look when you are sure that there should be a standardized code for your use case, but you are having trouble guessing which specification describes it.

> it's part of WebDAV and I'm not sure how correct it is to use it for other applications?

TL;DR: it's correct to use it for other applications.

The HTTP specification defines the [process](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.2) by which new codes can be added to the status code registry, and that process has been followed for the WebDAV codes.  So we can be confident that the meaning of 422 won't be replaced by some other semantic (for compatibility, status codes are retired -- see status code [306](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.6).)

The definition of 422 in the WebDAV specification is not WebDAV specific.

Furthermore, the behavior of clients that are not aware of the WebDAV specification is described in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6)

> a client MUST understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first  digit, and treat an unrecognized status code as being equivalent to the x00 status code of that class, with the exception that a recipient MUST NOT cache a response with an unrecognized status code.

You can also review [appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#appendix-B) of the WebDAV specification.

(As a side note, I think your concern is reasonable -- WebDAV *methods* are much harder to re-use outside of that context.)

---

Update 2022-07-12: the IANA registered reference for status code 422 is now [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-422-unprocessable-content) (HTTP Semantics).  We no longer need be concerned when we use that status code outside of a WebDAV context.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Makes sense. About `422` though, while often suggested in REST-related questions, it's part of WebDAV and I'm not sure how correct it is to use it for other applications?